# ¿Como hacer un toast con una imagen?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-toast

Digamos que es una app donde si el usuario llega al resultado se pretende mostrar un toast con una imagen y un texto haciendo referencia a que lo hizo bien, de igual forma para si lo hizo mal, mostrar lo correspondiente.

Se hacer el típico toast:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Correcto +100", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

Toast.makeText(this, "Inorrecto -100", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Pero de cierta forma es nefasto, incluso creo que el toast se puede definir desde antes (Como una variable) y de ahí ir poniendo lo que se vaya requiriendo (Incluida una imagen). ¿Cómo se pude hacer esto en kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de leer la documentación oficial [aquí](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts#CustomToastView), le hice unos pequeños cambios para que sea más fácil su uso.

Lo primero es create tu propio layout y llamarlo `custom_toast.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_toast_container"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="#DAAA">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:src="@drawable/check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Después, creas una "extension function" para `AppCompatActivity`:

```
fun AppCompatActivity.toast(status: ToastStatus, message: String, length: Int = Toast.LENGTH_LONG) {
    val inflater = layoutInflater
    val viewGroup: ViewGroup? = null
    val layout: ViewGroup = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, viewGroup, false) as ViewGroup
    val text: TextView = layout.findViewById(R.id.text)
    val image: ImageView = layout.findViewById(R.id.icon)
    val icon = when (status) {
        ToastStatus.SUCCESS -> R.drawable.check
        ToastStatus.ERROR -> R.drawable.error
    }
    image.setBackgroundResource(icon)
    text.text = message
    with (Toast(applicationContext)) {
        setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0)
        duration = length
        view = layout
        show()
    }
}
```

Como puedes ver, un parámetro es un `ToastStatus` el cuál es un `enum` que es el siguiente:

```
enum class ToastStatus {
    SUCCESS,
    ERROR
}
```

Lo bueno de esto es que puedes crear tus propios `ToastStatus`. Puedes añadir un `WARNING` o el que gustes.

También tendrás que añadir tus propios íconos, en este caso `check` y `error`.

Y para usar este toast, simplemente lo llamas desde una `Activity` de la siguiente manera:

```
toast(ToastStatus.SUCCESS, "Correcto +100")
```

o si quieres mostrar un error:

```
toast(ToastStatus.ERROR, "Incorrecto -100")
```